# IE 11 User Agent Strings

Tags: asp.net, user-agent, internet-explorer-11

I saw that you answered a question a while back about user agent string in IE 11 and I have a follow up to that.

I would much rather have my company upgrade to the latest version of .net 4.5 and the newest windows server OS, but that doesn't seem to be an option here.

There is already about a dozen files the APP_Browser folder and the mozilla.browser file seems to be conflicting with your suggested fix.

When I put a file with your code alone - everything works fine. When I include this mozilla.browser file, it goes back to not working...

Our mozilla.browser file stars like this:

```
<browser id="Mozilla" parentID="Default">
        <identification>
            <userAgent match="Mozilla" />
            <userAgent nonMatch="MME|Opera" />
        </identification>

        <capture>
            <userAgent match="Mozilla/(?'version'(?'major'\d+)(?'minor'\.\d+)\w*)" />
            <userAgent match=" (?'screenWidth'\d*)x(?'screenHeight'\d*)" />
        </capture>

        <capabilities>
            <capability name="browser"                         value="Mozilla" />
            <capability name="cookies"                         value="false" />
            <capability name="defaultScreenCharactersHeight"   value="40" />
            <capability name="defaultScreenCharactersWidth"    value="80" />
            <capability name="defaultScreenPixelsHeight"       value="480" />
            <capability name="defaultScreenPixelsWidth"        value="640" />
            <capability name="inputType"                       value="keyboard" />
            <capability name="isColor"                         value="true" />
            <capability name="isMobileDevice"                  value="false" />
            <capability name="majorversion"                    value="${major}" />
            <capability name="maximumRenderedPageSize"         value="300000" />
            <capability name="minorversion"                    value="${minor}" />
            <capability name="screenBitDepth"                  value="8" />
            <capability name="screenPixelsHeight"              value="${screenHeight}" />
            <capability name="screenPixelsWidth"               value="${screenWidth}" />
            <capability name="supportsBold"                    value="true" />
            <capability name="supportsCss"                     value="true" />
            <capability name="supportsDivNoWrap"               value="true" />
            <capability name="supportsFontName"                value="true" />
            <capability name="supportsFontSize"                value="true" />
            <capability name="supportsImageSubmit"             value="true" />
            <capability name="supportsItalic"                  value="true" />
            <capability name="type"                            value="Mozilla" />
            <capability name="version"                         value="${version}" />
        </capabilities>
    </browser>
```

...

I'm sure the solution lies int the parent hierarchy and the regular expression capture. Was wondering if you had any insights.

Comment: perhaps a link to the original post would help since you are addressing the whole site as a person referencing something in the past.

Answer (score 0):

I've just spent most of today struggling with this and found a whole bunch of different behaviors, but to summarize:

- ASP.NET 4.0 cannot handle I.E. 11's new User-Agent string - (Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.3; WOW64; Trident/7.0; rv:11.0) like Gecko - no matter what config file changes you make or hotfixes you install. If you want to handle this user agent string properly (so that, for instance, cookie-based session ids work correctly), you should upgrade to .NET 4.5.
- While there *may* be a reliable way to specify config settings that tell I.E. 11 to always use compatibility mode, I couldn't figure it out - X-UA-Compatibility may change how I.E. renders the page, but it doesn't change the user-agent it uses for the next request to the same server/site.
- I.E. 11 by default does send an older 'compatibility-mode' user-agent string for *intranet* sites. So when testing locally you may see everything work fine, but when somebody else tries to connect to the very same server with an IP address or a FQDN, it won't work. Actually I'm not quite sure how I.E. 11 determines whether something is on the intranet, in one case even just using the unqualified server name from another machine wasn't enough to make it think I was accessing an intranet site.
- I.E. 11 can be configured to always use compatibility-mode for particular websites, but you have to hunt for it in the Tools menu.

Personally I'd say by far the safest option is to upgrade to .NET 4.5.

Update: turns out my first point isn't strictly true. You can add a new entry to a .browser file in App_Browsers to recognise IE 11's user agent string, but it's still quite tricky getting it to work and I'm not sure exactly which options are needed. It starts:

```
<browser id="IE11" parentID="Mozilla">
<identification>
<userAgent match="Trident\/7.0; rv:(?'version'(?'major'\d+)(\.(?'minor'\d+)?)(?'letters'\w*))(?'extra'[^)]*)" />
<userAgent nonMatch="IEMobile" />
</identification>
<capture>
<userAgent match="Trident/(?'layoutVersion'\d+)" />
</capture>
<capabilities>
<capability name="browser"              value="IE" />
<capability name="layoutEngine"         value="Trident" />
```

...